# Shell Script - Download a file - Mysql replace

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a video script. it has embedded Youtube videos. I want replace them downloaded version mp4 videos.

this script has a mysql table. I want search "url_flv" field on table a youtube link if has a youtube link I want download it this command.
I want extract uniq_id field for file name

```
youtube-dl -o '/home/videoscript/uploads/videos/123456.mp4' -f 18 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFu5qXMuaJU
```

and I want replace mysql for downloaded versions:

original mysql:

table: pm_videos

fields:

```
id: 1200
uniq_id: 123456
url_flv: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFu5qXMuaJU
source_id: 3
```

I want change them.

```
id: 1200
uniq_id: 123456
url_flv: 123456.mp4
source_id: 1
```

Comment: So, how far did you get with your script?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!awk -f
/uniq_id/ {
  z = $2
}
{
  if (/url_flv/)
    print $1, z ".mp4"
  else
    print
}
```